# Alternative to keyword Search in Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, feed

As we all know , that search has been deprecated with V2.x for facebook API. Wanted to know is there any alternative provided by Facebook API to achieve the same functionality .
Any help is appreciated, as till now I have been successfully using the search with V1.1 and now that it is going to be deprecated completely I am unable to use the search functionality in future.
Please suggest any other way to retain the functionality

Comment: There is the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/), but that is only available to a limited set of FB partners. Apart from that, there is no way.